# Create multiple new dataframe columns from substring/regex matches in single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a catch-all column called "Misc", which contains optional sequences of characters. For example:

```
    Misc
    1. xxx=something;yyyblah=somethingelse;xyx=blah
    2. xyz=meh;yzxx=random;xyx=meh
```

I am really only interested in 4-5 values/cases of something=something; and I would like to create new columns and add them to my dataframe for those instances, and "." or NaN if they do not exist.
So if I was interested in xxx= ... ; and xyx=...; my code would do the following:

```
    Misc                                                xxx          xyx
    1. xxx=something;yyyblah=somethingelse;xyx=blah |  something  |  blah
    2. xyz=meh;yzxx=random;xyx=meh                  |  .          |  meh
```

All of the information in Misc will begin with a set of 20-30 strings, and end with ";". I have tried using regexes ...

```
    df['xxx'] = df.Misc.str.extract(r'*(xxx=)*;)$', expand=True)
```

but that does not seem to be working. I also thought about simply removing all instances I do not care about, and then splitting so I get consistency. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the capture group to match after `xxx=` instead of `xxx=` itself. The `(?:;|$)` checks for either `;` or end-of-line as terminators.

```py
df['xxx'] = df.Misc.str.extract(r'xxx=(.*?)(?:;|$)', expand=True)
df['xyx'] = df.Misc.str.extract(r'xyx=(.*?)(?:;|$)', expand=True)
```

Or you can [**`assign()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) these columns automatically in a comprehension:

```py
keys = ['xxx', 'xyx']
df = df.assign(**{key: df.Misc.str.extract(rf'{key}=(.*?)(?:;|$)', expand=True) for key in keys})
```

Output:

```
#                                               Misc                     xxx   xyx
# 0  1. xxx=something;yyyblah=somethingelse;xyx=blah               something  blah
# 1                   2. xyz=meh;yzxx=random;xyx=meh                     NaN   meh
# 2                             3. xxx=foo;xxxxy=bar                     foo   NaN
# 3              4. xxx=meh,blah/other=super 3;zzz=1  meh,blah/other=super 3   NaN
```

---

#### Timings

I couldn't get Andrej's answer to work on my end (reindexing error), but these are the other timings with 40K rows:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Misc':['1. xxx=something;yyyblah=somethingelse;xyx=blah','2. xyz=meh;yzxx=random;xyx=meh','3. xxx=foo;xxxxy=bar','4. xxx=meh,blah/other=super 3;zzz=1']})
>>> df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

>>> %timeit tdy(df)
75.5 ms ± 5.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit wwnde(df)
83.6 ms ± 1.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: With your approach (very simple, and probably computationally efficient, since I aim to throw out the others regardless), I get "wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1".

Looking at the data there are a few spots that could trip this up, though I do not see issued with the regex. 
1. Categories can be substrings, like xxx= xxxxy=. I do not think this is a problem
2. Categories can have more than one "=" like xxx=meh,blah/other=super
3. All kinds of punctuation can occur after "=", except ";", which is the termination char

Comment: @ShaneK Ah sorry, had a typo. Fixed now. I tested with those 2 extra cases and they work on my end. Updated the answer with those examples.

Comment: @ShaneK Also added timings with 40,000 rows.

Comment: All of you are awesome, thanks for taking time out of your life to share your knowledge. @tdy, this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

To expand all parameters, you can use [`.str.extractall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall):

```
x = (
    df.Misc.str.extractall(r"([^=\s]+)=([^;]+);?")
    .groupby(level=0)[[0, 1]]
    .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x[0], x[1])))
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .fillna("N/A")
)

df_out = pd.concat([df, x], axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
                                              Misc        xxx        yyyblah   xyx  xyz    yzxx
0  1. xxx=something;yyyblah=somethingelse;xyx=blah  something  somethingelse  blah  N/A     N/A
1                   2. xyz=meh;yzxx=random;xyx=meh        N/A            N/A   meh  meh  random
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try Named groups.

```
df.Misc.str.extract('(?P<xxx>(?<=^xxx\=)\w+)|(?P<xyx>(?<=xyx\=)\w+$)')
```

Or

Use `(?<=X)Y` also known as Positive lookbehind assertion. Where `Y` is matched only if `X` is on its left. Chain this with `str.extract`.

```
df[['xxx','xyx']]=df.Misc.str.extract('((?<=^xxx\=)\w+)'),df.Misc.str.extract('((?<=xyx\=)\w+$)')
```

Either solution should result into

```
      Misc                                            xxx   xyx
0  xxx=something;yyyblah=somethingelse;xyx=blah  something  blah
1                   xyz=meh;yzxx=random;xyx=meh        NaN   meh
```

Comment: I like the way this was done as well, though I am receiving ""None of [Index(['xxx', 'xyx'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]""

Comment: Which specific line is giving you an error?

Comment: ['xxx','xyx']]=df.Misc.str.extract('((?<=^xxx\=)\w+)'),df.Misc.str.extract('((?<=xyx\=)\w+$)')

Comment: You mean `df[['xxx','xyx']]`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, my copy/paste skills were lacking on that comment.