# How to get the matched groups in regex Python and save it as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, data-cleaning, string-matching

I have a dataframe and i want to find out, if there was any mentions of the firms that i'm looking for in `DocumentIdentifier` column. probably it should be done through Regex groups, but I'm not sure and currently i use `contains()`.

The data looks like this:

| GKGRECORDID | DATE | SourceCommonName | DocumentIdentifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20160101223000-T417 | sueddeutsche.de | "http://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/vw-skandal-schein-und-sein-1.2802686" |
| 3 | 20151231060000-T360 | focus.de | "http://www.focus.de/finanzen/boerse/volkswagen-skandal-im-news-ticker-vw-betriebsrat-fordert-nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-fuer-autobauer_id_5183047.html" |
| 4 | 20151231100000-T827 | welt.de | "http://www.welt.de/regionales/niedersachsen/article150494146/Osterloh-will-fuer-VW-Nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-mit-externen-Fachleuten.html" |
| 5 | 20151231101500-T428 | focus.de | "http://www.focus.de/regional/wolfsburg/auto-osterloh-will-fuer-vw-nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-mit-externen-fachleuten_id_5183279.html" |
| 6 | 20151231140000-T543 | focus.de | "http://www.focus.de/finanzen/news/wirtschaftsticker/unternehmen-osterloh-will-fuer-vw-nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-mit-externen-fachleuten_id_5183525.html" |

Using `contain()` method, which filters the data correctly, however i don't think that's the right way of finding, which firm it matches. My code looks like this:

```
firm_pattern='|'.join(['adidas', 'Airbus', 'Allianz','Volkswagen','VW')
pattern = '|'.join(['welt.de','focus.de'])
results=[results[(results['DocumentIdentifier'].str.contains(f'{firm_pattern}', case=False, na=False)) & 
                                         (results['SourceCommonName'].str.contains(pattern,case=False, na=False))]
```

What i want is to find out which of the firms it matches and create as new columns as it needs like for first row in a new column like `Firm1` should be written `vw`. For second row in `Firm1` column `vw` and for `Firm2` `Volkswagen`.

what i found out is that i can get the groups using `.group()` method.

```
re.search(r'(volkswagen)|(vw)', 
'http://www.focus.de/finanzen/boerse/volkswagen-skandal-im-news-ticker-vw-betriebsrat-fordert-nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-fuer-autobauer_id_5183047.html'
).group(0) #0-1 returns volkswagen only but it should return vw as well
```

how can i improve my code?

### Edit:

If you want to use my data copy this code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'GKGRECORDID': [1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'DATE': ['20160101223000-T417', '20151231060000-T360', '20151231100000-T827', '20151231101500-T428', '20151231140000-T543'],
    'SourceCommonName': ['sueddeutsche.de', 'focus.de', 'welt.de', 'focus.de', 'focus.de'],
    'DocumentIdentifier': [
        'http://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/vw-skandal-schein-und-sein-1.2802686',
        'http://www.focus.de/finanzen/boerse/volkswagen-skandal-im-news-ticker-vw-betriebsrat-fordert-nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-fuer-autobauer_id_5183047.html',
        'http://www.welt.de/regionales/niedersachsen/article150494146/Osterloh-will-fuer-VW-Nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-mit-externen-Fachleuten.html',
        'http://www.focus.de/regional/wolfsburg/auto-osterloh-will-fuer-vw-nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-mit-externen-fachleuten_id_5183279.html',
        'http://www.focus.de/finanzen/news/wirtschaftsticker/unternehmen-osterloh-will-fuer-vw-nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-mit-externen-fachleuten_id_5183525.html'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


print(df)
```

Comment: Have you done any research? I googled something like your question title and found this, which looks like good inspiration: [Create multiple new dataframe columns from substring/regex matches in single column](/q/67154532/4518341)

Comment: Please reduce into a [mre]. If the other columns aren't relevant to the problem, don't include them. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). And please show the desired output in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer. the `re.findall` method is good alternative. `findall` returns a tuple of found variables and then those can be put into a list (which is ignoring empty strings), that can be handy.

My Code:

```
[value for tpl in re.findall(r'(volkswagen)|(vw)|(BMW)', 
 'http://www.focus.de/finanzen/boerse/-bmw-volkswagen-skandal-im-news-ticker-vw-betriebsrat-fordert-nachhaltigkeitsbeirat-fuer-autobauer_id_5183047.html',
       re.IGNORECASE) for value in tpl if value != '']

result>> ['bmw', 'volkswagen', 'vw']
```

As @wjandrea suggested from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67154768/4575197) `df.column.str.extract(regex expression)` can be usefull too:

```
#Make sure you use double brackets 
df[['1','2','3']]=df.DocumentIdentifier.str.extract(r'(volkswagen)|(vw)|(BMW)')
```