# I can't use split to separate the data

Tags: python-3.x

```
sas_url = 'https://telemetria2023.blob.core.windows.net/geolocalizacao/edbaa694-0988-4b38-b45f-10835fc2272f/29/2023/11/02/22/30/66jaxcmrz4gwy'
geo = pd.read_json(sas_url)
geo = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(geo)

geo[["alt", "lat", "lon"]] = (geo["telemetry"].str.split(": ", expand=True))
```

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbL4J.png)

separate latitude, longitude and altitude

Comment: There are three `': '` inside each row, so `split` is going to produce six substrings.

Comment: Sou novo em python, como ficaria o código?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), post the [full error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) as text. Also, it would be easier to help if we have a [mre] (see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391)) where we can reproduce your string values without having to download them from an external source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create multiple new dataframe columns from substring/regex matches in single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67154532/create-multiple-new-dataframe-columns-from-substring-regex-matches-in-single-col)

Comment: `pd.read_json(sas_url)` returns a DataFrame already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd

sas_url = "https://telemetria2023.blob.core.windows.net/geolocalizacao/edbaa694-0988-4b38-b45f-10835fc2272f/29/2023/11/02/22/30/66jaxcmrz4gwy"
geo = pd.read_json(sas_url)

geo = pd.concat([geo, geo.pop("telemetry").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(geo)
```

Prints:

```
                                    applicationId component                       deviceId              enqueuedTime  enrichments  messageProperties messageSource      schema                  templateId   alt       lat        lon
geolocation  edbaa694-0988-4b38-b45f-10835fc2272f   sensors  my-phone-as-device-4pGmUfiEco  2023-11-02T22:30:04.955Z          NaN                NaN     telemetry  default@v1  dtmi:azureiot:q9ecxa3st4ir  28.4 -3.820995 -38.556383
```